# extract iphone app with json-framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, cocoa-touch

Whe i try try to  extract the value:  `18 total`, from that json string:

```
{"items": 
    [["3 lost"], 
     ["18 total"]
    ], 
"id": "26", 
"service": "bizi", 
"title": "my title"}
```

I obtain instead : `("18 total")`

I'm using `[[object valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:1];`

Where is my fault?

Comment: How did you check you got ("18 total") ? By some log statement? Can you mention it?

Comment: Hi!Yes, i check it by a NsLog

Comment: The string `"18 total"` is inside its own array. What does `[[[object valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0]` give you?

Comment: TX!! your comment solved the question! I didnt use the second objectAtindex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON code is returning another array for that object (enclosed in "[]")

Try:

```
[[[object valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

"items" is an array containing 2 arrays, each containing a single string item. Assuming ("18 total") comes from a log statement, the brackets indicate an array with one item: "18 total"

The code you will need is:

```
[[[object valueForKey:@"items"] objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:0];
```